# How to Change Default Error Text in Yup/Formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

If I click on the email input field, the field says "Enter Your Email". This was set by me. However, during I'm typing,when the validation check isn't fulfilled, it says 'enter a valid email' something, which is a default, not written by me.

In case of wrong password, since I am using .matches(), I get my desired text printed on the screen. How can I do so for email as well?

Here's my Yup object:

```
const schema = Yup.object({
  email: Yup
    .string()
    .email()
    .required('Please Enter your Email'),
  password: Yup
    .string()
    .required('Please Enter your password')
    .matches(
      /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/,
      "Must Contain 8 Characters, One Uppercase, One Lowercase, One Number and one special case Character"
    )
});
```

This is how my Formik component looks like:

```
 <Formik
            initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
              }, 1000);
            }}
            validationSchema={schema}
          >
            {props => {
              const {
                values: { email, password },
                errors,
                touched,
                handleChange,
                isValid,
                setFieldTouched
              } = props;
              const change = (name: string, e: { persist: () => void; }) => {
                e.persist();
                handleChange(e);
                setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
              };
              return (
                <form style={{ width: '100%' }} onSubmit={_ => alert('Submitted!')}>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    fullWidth
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"      
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    fullWidth
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                    helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ""}
                    error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                    label="Password"
                    type="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, "password")}
                  />
</Formik>
```

In Formik props, errors : An object containing error messages of the field.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found that the accepted answer is correct but can be incomplete in some cases.
Placing the cursor into a field and tabbing out of it can trigger a Yup "[type error](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtypeerrormessage-string-schema)".

A default Yup type error is a verbose and non-user-friendly thing ;)

I would extend the answer from AndreasT to read:

```
email:  Yup
.string()
.email('this will be displayed when email is wrong')
.required('this will be displayed when empty')
.typeError('A number is required')
```

[Here is the article](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/gmuuizvueo-custom-type-checking-error-messages-with-yup) that turned me on to this answer.

Answer (score 22):

add your preferred error string to your email schema:

```
email:  Yup
.string()
.email('this will be displayed when email is wrong')
.required('this will be displayed when empty')
```

codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-shape-lijo2

Answer (score 5):

for custom validations using `test` method:

```js
serialNumber: Yup.string()
  .max(19, 'invalid')
  .required('required')
  .test({
    name: 'serialNumberErr',
    message: i18next.t('serialNumberErr'),
    test: (value) => customValidator(value),
  }),
```

Comment: This works for me because I found an option to customize the error message on a `min` method, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
  fullname: yup.string()
           .min(3)
           .required('This is rendered if you try to submit an empty email field'),
  email: yup.string()
        .email('This shows when you input an invalid email addres')
        .required('This is rendered if you try to submit an empty email field'),
  password: yup.string()
        .required('This is rendered if you try to submit an empty email field')
        .matches(
           /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$/,
           "This is rendered if the password does not meet requirement"),
  confirmPassword: yup.string()
        .oneOf([yup.ref('password'), null], "Password mismatch")
        .required('This is rendered if you try to submit an empty email field')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

In case of handling only string type errors which does not accept message params following syntax works.

```
signatureImage: Yup.string().required( 'Live Signature is required' ).typeError( 'Live Signature is required' ),
```